# Flutter Isar linkproperty.add() issue

Tags: database, flutter, dart, flutter-isar

I am creating a user (collection element) to be stored in my chat (collection element). chat contains IsarLinks<user>.
I create a user and save it (which it correctly does). but when I add it this error pops up.

[image]

And this is the line where error arises

```
final _chat = chat()
  ..users.add(store)
  ..chatname = _user.name;
```

further this is where I save the chat

```
Future<void> MakeChatwithUserAsync(chat _chat)async{
  final isar = await db;

  var isarCollection = isar.chats;
  await isar.writeTxn(() async {
    isar.chats.putSync(_chat);
    // _chat.users.loadSync();
    await _chat.users.save();
  });
  print("chat saved");
}
```

Isar version used is isar-3.0.0-dev.7
and flutter doctor shows everything fine
How can this be fixed?

I expected it to work perfectly as I followed the docs, but this did not happen. I tried exploring the function definitions and scrolled on the internet but it was of no use. I want to
complete my project of making WhatsApp like app with flutter

Comment: the `store` variable needs to be put in isar first before `add`-ing them to the users collection

Answer (score 0):

You have to save User data before calling .save() function. in that way, users object will be linked with Isar Object

```
await isar.writeTxn(() async {
    isar.users.putAll(_chat.users);
    isar.chats.putSync(_chat);
    await _chat.users.save();
  });
```